# Goodness of fit for multi dimensional scaling

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, goodness-of-fit, multidimensional-scaling

What is considered to be an acceptable value for goodness-of-fit in multi-dimensional scaling (MDS). I tried to run an MDS analysis on my data with four dimensions in R. The goodness of fit comes around 0.35. Is this considered too low?

Is there anyway to improve the goodness-of-fit without increasing the dimensions?

Comment: The type of (un)fit (called stress in MDS) used, or the way it might be standardized for compatibility - entirely depends on the software you use. So 0.35 says very little to us. Sometimes reconsidering the model of MDS (e.g. changing metric to ordinal) can increase fit.

Comment: I used cmdscale in R.